# How to fix EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) watchdog termination?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, crash

I am running into a watchdog termination crash. After watching [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-using-crash-reports-and-device-logs) WWDC session and reading the relevant documentation about [watchdog crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations), I suspect there is some kind of deadlock.

But I am unable to understand how my code is causing deadlock. I have removed stack traces of some threads here because of the character limit. The complete crash log can be found in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/AwaisFayyaz/cdcb7e64f3b74391c6ef2d23bca65c16)

```
Incident Identifier: 5E8D976C-94FC-4400-A729-20BD48E26C7C
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,3
Process:             Fhetch [73637]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3581EBF4-AE49-411D-B444-10D2617B1D45/XYZ.app/XYZ
Identifier:          com.XYZ.APP
Version:             1.1.3 (18)
AppStoreTools:       13E500
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,3:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.XYZ.APP [2854]

Date/Time:           2022-04-25 14:04:47.1725 -0400
Launch Time:         2022-04-24 23:09:42.3116 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.4.1 (19E258)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.53.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.XYZ.APP>:73637 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Foreground
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-update
WatchdogVisibility: Background
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.260 (user 5.280, system 3.980), 15% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.101, 0% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd27bdc kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4eef1fc _dispatch_kq_poll + 228 (event_kevent.c:750)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4eefc20 _dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership + 444 (event_kevent.c:2209)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbf54 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 328 (queue.c:1690)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbb28 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144 (queue.c:1774)
5   CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa94 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 264 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4059)
6   FHKit                           0x00000001016c55c0 closure #1 in static FHDataManager.transfer<A>(_:intoContext:) + 1288 (DataManager+ManagedObjects.swift:56)
7   FHKit                           0x000000010166124c thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   FHKit                           0x00000001016612ac thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bf834 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3942)
10  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa5c -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 208 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4053)
11  FHKit                           0x00000001016c4e98 static FHDataManager.transfer<A>(_:intoContext:) + 576 (DataManager+ManagedObjects.swift:49)
12  FHKit                           0x00000001016c4404 static FHDataManager.transfer<A>(_:intoContext:) + 951300 (DataManager+ManagedObjects.swift:39)
13  FHKit                           0x0000000101776b84 FHIdentifiableEntity.hasSameId<A>(as:) + 596 (IdentifiableEntity.swift:36)
14  FHKit                           0x0000000101698a5c FHSubmittableUserAction.supercedes(_:) + 3012 (SubmittableUserAction.swift:77)
15  FHKit                           0x000000010186c9bc closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in static FHActionManager.process(submittableUserAction:fromContext:) + 112 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:419)
16  FHKit                           0x000000010166124c thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  FHKit                           0x00000001016612ac thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
18  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bf834 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3942)
19  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa5c -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 208 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4053)
20  FHKit                           0x000000010186c818 closure #1 in closure #1 in static FHActionManager.process(submittableUserAction:fromContext:) + 668 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:417)
21  FHKit                           0x00000001019cc734 closure #1 in closure #1 in static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.remove(operationBlockIf:) + 60 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:233)
22  FHKit                           0x00000001019cc790 thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FHNetworkOperation) -> (@unowned Bool, @error @owned Error) + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
23  FHKit                           0x00000001019cd864 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FHNetworkOperation) -> (@unowned Bool, @error @owned Error) + 32 (<compiler-generated>:0)
24  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001c9cbec30 _ArrayProtocol.filter(_:) + 1000 (ArrayType.swift:73)
25  FHKit                           0x00000001019cc698 closure #1 in static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.remove(operationBlockIf:) + 224 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:231)
26  FHKit                           0x00000001016ca4b4 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error) + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
27  FHKit                           0x00000001019cd828 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error)partial apply + 32 (<compiler-generated>:0)
28  FHKit                           0x00000001016cde5c static FHThreadManager.synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 924 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:195)
29  FHKit                           0x00000001016ca460 synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 88 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:211)
30  FHKit                           0x00000001019c7624 static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.remove(operationBlockIf:) + 4109860 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:229)
31  FHKit                           0x000000010186c3f0 closure #1 in static FHActionManager.process(submittableUserAction:fromContext:) + 728 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:409)
32  FHKit                           0x00000001016ca4b4 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error) + 24 (<compiler-generated>:0)
33  FHKit                           0x000000010186c510 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error) + 32 (<compiler-generated>:0)
34  FHKit                           0x00000001016cde5c static FHThreadManager.synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 924 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:195)
35  FHKit                           0x00000001016ca460 synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 88 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:211)
36  FHKit                           0x000000010186c0e4 static FHActionManager.process(submittableUserAction:fromContext:) + 476 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:439)
37  FHKit                           0x0000000101867638 static FHActionManager.process<A>(actionForRecord:fromContext:) + 680 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:390)
38  FHKit                           0x0000000101866e4c static FHActionManager.process(action:forContent:fromContext:bypassingServerInteraction:withTrustedTimestamps:) + 2666060 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:26)
39  Fhetch                          0x00000001006e4088 closure #1 in FHChatTableViewController.ensureMessageIsRead(message:) + 2015368 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:668)
40  Fhetch                          0x000000010053e2c4 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
41  Fhetch                          0x000000010053e324 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
42  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bf834 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3942)
43  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
44  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbc90 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56 (queue.c:1028)
45  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa94 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 264 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4059)
46  Fhetch                          0x00000001006df868 FHChatTableViewController.ensureMessageIsRead(message:) + 1032 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:658)
47  Fhetch                          0x00000001006dc9d0 closure #1 in FHChatTableViewController.directlyInsertRows(for:reloadTable:resortTable:) + 3640 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:315)
48  Fhetch                          0x00000001006e0730 thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FHContentMO) -> (@owned FHChatCellContentData?, @error @owned Error) + 2000688 (<compiler-generated>:0)
49  Fhetch                          0x00000001006e4a28 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FHContentMO) -> (@owned FHChatCellContentData?, @error @owned Error) + 2017832 (<compiler-generated>:0)
50  libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001c9e48ce0 Sequence.compactMap<A>(_:) + 1224 (SequenceAlgorithms.swift:807)
51  Fhetch                          0x00000001006db6ac FHChatTableViewController.directlyInsertRows(for:reloadTable:resortTable:) + 276 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:289)
52  Fhetch                          0x00000001006d80b8 FHChatTableViewController.updateRows(for:) + 1448 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:568)
53  Fhetch                          0x00000001006d6ae8 FHChatTableViewController.processCoreDataNotification(_:) + 7964 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:108)
54  Fhetch                          0x00000001006d45ac closure #1 in FHChatTableViewController.setupCoreDataNotifications() + 1588 (ChatTableViewController+CoreData.swift:38)
55  Fhetch                          0x00000001005d8360 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Notification) -> () + 918368 (<compiler-generated>:0)
56  Foundation                      0x00000001c69ee564 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 348 (NSNotification.m:327)
57  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c51f7324 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:652)
58  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c5293ac4 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52 (CFNotificationCenter.c:173)
59  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c5266cc0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 456 (CFNotificationCenter.c:199)
60  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c520d39c _CFXNotificationPost + 728 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1147)
61  Foundation                      0x00000001c69d4704 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 96 (NSNotification.m:560)
62  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9e2628 -[NSManagedObjectContext _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 468 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:8290)
63  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9c87e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1576 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:7922)
64  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfbbc -[NSManagedObjectContext _postRefreshedObjectsNotificationAndClearList] + 200 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:7471)
65  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9be278 -[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:] + 108 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:7550)
66  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bf8b0 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 280 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3949)
67  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
68  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edaf48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2622)
69  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edab98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7770)
70  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c521e2f0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
71  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c51d81f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
72  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c51eb6b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
73  GraphicsServices                0x00000001e1285374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
74  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c7b50e88 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
75  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c78d25ec UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
76  Fhetch                          0x00000001005ca818 main + 64 (AppDelegate.swift:31)
77  dyld                            0x0000000100fc1ce4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)


Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd281a4 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c5277658 __CFSocketManager + 644 (CFSocket.c:1343)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002369969ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e68 thread_start + 8


Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd28178 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000023698d9ac _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   FHKit                           0x00000001016ccad8 lock(_:) + 648 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:144)
3   FHKit                           0x00000001016cde20 static FHThreadManager.synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 864 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:192)
4   FHKit                           0x00000001016ca460 synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 88 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:211)
5   FHKit                           0x000000010186c0e4 static FHActionManager.process(submittableUserAction:fromContext:) + 476 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:439)
6   FHKit                           0x0000000101867638 static FHActionManager.process<A>(actionForRecord:fromContext:) + 680 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:390)
7   FHKit                           0x0000000101866e4c static FHActionManager.process(action:forContent:fromContext:bypassingServerInteraction:withTrustedTimestamps:) + 2666060 (ActionManager+Processing.swift:26)
8   FHKit                           0x00000001019d4790 closure #1 in FHUserNotificationMessageArrivedInfo.merge(intoContext:) + 5512 (NewMessageArrived.swift:118)
9   FHKit                           0x000000010166124c thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  FHKit                           0x00000001016612ac thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bf834 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3942)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edc0b8 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 64 (queue.c:1028)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbb44 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 172 (queue.c:1785)
15  CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa94 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 264 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4059)
16  FHKit                           0x00000001019d2ff0 FHUserNotificationMessageArrivedInfo.merge(intoContext:) + 1364 (NewMessageArrived.swift:48)
17  Fhetch                          0x0000000100547994 FHChatTableViewController.processAnyPendingNotifications() + 326036 (ChatTableViewController.swift:214)
18  Fhetch                          0x00000001005472a8 closure #1 in FHChatTableViewController.appDidBecomeActive() + 324264 (ChatTableViewController.swift:183)
19  Fhetch                          0x00000001005059ac thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 52 (<compiler-generated>:0)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecae68 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede280 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 680 (inline_internal.h:2622)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede96c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:6935)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236996080 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2612)
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd27bdc kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4eef1fc _dispatch_kq_poll + 228 (event_kevent.c:750)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4eefc20 _dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership + 444 (event_kevent.c:2209)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbf54 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 328 (queue.c:1690)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edbb28 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144 (queue.c:1774)
5   CoreData                        0x00000001cc9bfa94 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 264 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4059)
6   FHKit                           0x00000001018b1034 closure #1 in static FHAPIEndpointDescribing.execute<A>(withRequestData:responseHandler:) + 10748 (EndpointDescribing.swift:308)
7   FHKit                           0x00000001018b4324 partial apply for closure #1 in static FHAPIEndpointDescribing.execute<A>(withRequestData:responseHandler:) + 92 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   FHKit                           0x00000001018ab054 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 268 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   CFNetwork                       0x00000001c5a0c0bc __40-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClassInfo:]_block_invoke + 532 (LocalSession.mm:675)
10  CFNetwork                       0x00000001c5a1d208 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke_2 + 196 (LocalSessionTask.mm:543)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecae68 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ed4124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ed4cb4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444 (queue.c:3944)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edf500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002369960bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd28178 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000023698d9ac _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   FHKit                           0x00000001016ccad8 lock(_:) + 648 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:144)
3   FHKit                           0x00000001016cde20 static FHThreadManager.synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 864 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:192)
4   FHKit                           0x00000001016ca460 synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 88 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:211)
5   FHKit                           0x00000001019cc8a4 static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.popNextOperation() + 124 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:248)
6   FHKit                           0x00000001019ccd80 closure #1 in closure #1 in static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.resume() + 88 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:300)
7   FHKit                           0x0000000101931048 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   FHKit                           0x00000001019c330c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out ()) + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   FHKit                           0x00000001016f3130 closure #1 in static FHKeychain.Storage.runPendingBlocks() + 64 (Keychain+Storage.swift:83)
10  FHKit                           0x0000000101840dd4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 52 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a0aa9c __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:1545)
12  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a1ce14 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104 (NSOperation.m:1564)
13  Foundation                      0x00000001c69f51c4 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:2189)
14  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a064e0 -[NSOperation start] + 788 (NSOperation.m:2206)
15  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a09ae8 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:2220)
16  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a17c90 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184 (NSOperation.m:2231)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edb830 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148 (queue.c:560)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecfeec _dispatch_continuation_pop + 500 (inline_internal.h:2622)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecf558 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 588 (queue.c:835)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede164 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (inline_internal.h:0)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede96c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:6935)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236996080 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2612)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fcd28178 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000023698d9ac _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   FHKit                           0x00000001016ccad8 lock(_:) + 648 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:144)
3   FHKit                           0x00000001016cde20 static FHThreadManager.synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 864 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:192)
4   FHKit                           0x00000001016ca460 synchronized<A>(_:shouldLogInfo:_:) + 88 (ThreadAndQueueManagement.swift:211)
5   FHKit                           0x00000001019cc8a4 static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.popNextOperation() + 124 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:248)
6   FHKit                           0x00000001019ccd80 closure #1 in closure #1 in static FHNetworkOperationsQueue.resume() + 88 (NetworkOperationsQueue.swift:300)
7   FHKit                           0x0000000101931048 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   FHKit                           0x00000001019c330c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out ()) + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   FHKit                           0x00000001016f3130 closure #1 in static FHKeychain.Storage.runPendingBlocks() + 64 (Keychain+Storage.swift:83)
10  FHKit                           0x0000000101840dd4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 52 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a0aa9c __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:1545)
12  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a1ce14 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 104 (NSOperation.m:1564)
13  Foundation                      0x00000001c69f51c4 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:2189)
14  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a064e0 -[NSOperation start] + 788 (NSOperation.m:2206)
15  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a09ae8 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 24 (NSOperation.m:2220)
16  Foundation                      0x00000001c6a17c90 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184 (NSOperation.m:2231)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4edb830 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148 (queue.c:560)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecca2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecfeec _dispatch_continuation_pop + 500 (inline_internal.h:2622)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ecf558 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 588 (queue.c:835)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede164 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (inline_internal.h:0)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c4ede96c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:6935)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236996080 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2612)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236995e54 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000001   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x000000016f8ffb88
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000403
    x8: 0x0000000000000400   x9: 0x000000021ea52580  x10: 0x0000000000000400  x11: 0x00000000000020ff
   x12: 0x0000000101014660  x13: 0x001ffe2000000000  x14: 0x0000000066400000  x15: 0x000000021ead0208
   x16: 0x0000000000000177  x17: 0xbb3000021ea51990  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000403
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x000000016f8ffb88
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x000000016f8ffb88  x26: 0x000000028080e580  x27: 0x0000000000020400
   x28: 0x000000021ea52580   fp: 0x000000016f8ffb70   lr: 0x00000001c4eef1fc
    sp: 0x000000016f8ffb10   pc: 0x00000001fcd27bdc     cpsr: 0x1000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Can you identify which threads might be causing deadlock? maybe there is some other problem?

This is how it looks in the crashes organizer in XCode.

[image: XCode crashes organizer screenshot]

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are calling a `performBlockAndWait` inside another `performBlockAndWait`, if it's the same context (or something like that), you should have a deadlock. Just try to reproduce it to check that embricking two `performAndWait`

Comment: I have used a 'performBlockAndWait' inside another 'performBlockAndWait' in a sample playground. It has not caused any problem. But this is true that the calling thread is blocked until all the nested blocks have finished executing.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, `Thread 0` crashed because it did not get access to the queue used by a `NSManagedObjectContext` in line 5 with `performBlockAndWait`. The same queue has apparently also been used in the same thread at other lines with `performBlockAndWait` (10, 19, 45…). This is no problem, since `performBlockAndWait` can be called re-entrantly, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506364-performandwait).
However, it has apparently also been used by other threads with `performBlockAndWait` (`Thread 9`, line 15; `Thread 11`, line 5). It seems to me that one of these threads allocated some common resource that `Thread 0` needs to complete its work - a deadlock.
It is not possible for me to find out what this critical resource is. Deadlocks are often hard to find.
A trivial suggestion that may break you code is to replace a `performBlockAndWait` by a `performBlock` and see if the affected thread continues running, even if the code is broken. Maybe this gives you some hint where to look for the problem.

Comment: I was executing some code on background thread using `DispatchQueue.global(qos:.userinitiated).async { //my code here}`. 
When I executed this code on the main thread, this issue was resolved. 

But i will revert it to the background thread and then debug using the hints you provided. 

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Calling closures from notifications async fixes this. You can look at the memory graph to understand this.

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail? maybe share a code snippet that will help to understand what you are saying.